# Unable to connect to my MYSQL Azure from my Webapp - 1045, "Access denied for user 'dbadmin'@'xx.xx.xx.x' (using password: YES)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, mysql-error-1045, azure-mysql-database

I keep receiving the following error in my Webapp

```
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'dbadmin'@'xx.xx.xx.x' (using password: YES)")
```

**MySQL Azure:**

- Hosted in Region > France Central
- Allowed Access to Azure Services
- Created through Azure portal with username "dbadmin" and server "jetbase"

SQLAlchemy db_uri looks like this

```
mysql://dbadmin@jetbase:'mysecretpassword'@jetbase.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/jetdb
```

**Webapp**:

Hosted in France Central as well

The same docker image when run locally on my dev computer, can access the database (I manually added the ip in the client IP addresses under Security.)

Can someone please help me debug this ?

Comment: According to the connection string, it seems that you're using the default MySQL driver through SQLAlchemy, which is mysql-python, right? I believe mysql-python is legacy. Can you try to use MySQL-Connector-python (version 1.2.3+) or PyMySQL (version 0.9.3+) ? 
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqlconnector or https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.pymysql

Comment: Actually, PyMySQL might be the best option according to SQLAlchemy doc.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the wierd thing, my password had an exclamation mark '!' and turns out it wasnt getting parsed properly and I kept getting the error 'Access denied for user@XX.XX.XX.XX (Password = yes)

I switched it to a "*" and it works fine now.

I also had to remove the single quotes around the password from the db_uri

```
mysql://dbadmin@jetbase:mysecretpasswordwithoutquotes@jetbase.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/jetdb
```

> Ps: The strange thing is that, the same docker container when run
>   locally on my computer with the password containing a !, works fine.
>   it works from MySQL work bench as well but just fails from App
>   services (webapp) in Azure. I'm guessing Azure App services encodes the db_uri
>   and messes up the "!" in the password

Comment: I had the same issue and after removing exclamation mark from connection string, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I can give 2 ideas, with the provided information :

- the encoding of database URL in your web app client. We have similar
  DB url syntax (with "@" in username) for our PG instances. In our
  servers, we replaced it with "%40" for it to work.
- account dbadmin is
  not allowed from you webserver IP (maybe the IP is not static, maybe
  it is not the one you think of, it really depends on the hosting of
  your webapp). I imagine you double checked that already.

We can try debugging together if you want at StationF